# Can't find reference to SQLXML in Visual Studio 2005 SSIS Package

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005, sqlxml

I had a project I was working on in Visual Studio 2008, when the requirements changed and now it needs to be done in 2005.  I was using SQLXML objects from Microsoft.Data.SqlXml, but now when I downgraded I cannot find this in the add reference pop up box.

Does anyone know why this isn't showing up and how I can make it show up?  I tried uninstalling and reinstalling SQLXML, and have updated VS2005 to SP3

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add references that are not in VS2005 script component add references box, put the assembly you are trying to add a reference to to

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\90\SDK\Assemblies

Then when you go to add reference it should appear.